# Autosizing for views increases distance between views in landscape mode

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiinterfaceorientation, autosize

I have an `iPhone` app, It should support both `landscape` and `portrait` orientation.I have set `Use Autolayout` as `NO`.

In `portrait` orientation , my `view` appears as
[image]

In `landscape` orientation , my `view` appears as
[image]

I have set the `autosizing` for both the `views` like the below image

[image]

Why the distance between the views are increasing on landscape mode? Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone can correct me if I am wrong but it seems like this is the correct behavior to me.  The views are not resizing and are not fixed to any one side of your superview.  The superview is just getting wider, and so the area between them becomes bigger. 
If you want to set them at a certain location and dont want to use autolayout then the best way is just to set the frames where you want them when a rotation occurs.  You can do this in two steps:
First set up your frames- i like to define a nice structure as follows

```
//Use this define to set frames for views
#define TAG_RECT( tag, x, y, width, height ) \
[NSValue valueWithCGRect:CGRectMake(x, y, width, height)], \
[NSNumber numberWithInteger:tag]
```

You then set up your frames in your `viewDidLoad:`  A good way to know where to place your view is by copying your view controller in storyboard and paste it to the side. then you can change it to landscape orientation and place the views exactly where you want them and just look at what the position and dimensions are. dont forget to set your tags for your views.

```
// Collect the frame positions for elements in portrait mode
    NSMutableDictionary *portraitPositions = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
// You only have two views, but if you have more its nice to do it in a loop
    for (NSInteger i = 1; i <= 2; i++) {
        UIView *view = [self.view viewWithTag:i];

        [portraitPositions setObject:[NSValue valueWithCGRect:view.frame] forKey:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:i]];
    }
    self.portraitFrames = [portraitPositions copy];

    // Let's build the landscape frame positions dictionary
    if ((UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)) {
        //Set up frames for variables in iPad version
        self.landscapeFrames = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                TAG_RECT(1, 325, 100, 375, 90),     // view one
                                TAG_RECT(2, 525, 100, 375, 90),     // view two 
                                nil];
    }
```

Next whenever your view rotates you need to layout the cooresponding frame set

```
- (void) willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {
    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(self.interfaceOrientation)) {    
        // Lay out for landscape mode
        [self layoutForFrameSet:self.landscapeFrames];
    }
    else if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(self.interfaceOrientation)) {
        // Lay out for portrait mode
        [self layoutForFrameSet:self.portraitFrames];
    }
}


- (void)layoutForFrameSet:(NSDictionary *)frames {
    for (NSNumber *key in frames.allKeys) {
        [self.view viewWithTag:[key integerValue]].frame = [[frames objectForKey:key] CGRectValue];
    }
}
```

Sorry if this is more complicated but this is the best way to have your views be placed exactly where you want them without autolayout

Comment: `- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation: duration:` is better to do this than `layoutSubviews`.

Comment: @johnMa why is that?  I have used both in the past, but why is the other better? I thought 'layoutSubviews'. is it just because she is only considering when her view changes orientations?

Comment: @horsejockey : Can you please help me in programmatically writing code for autosizing the uiview  for the above image?Is it self.testView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingNone; ?

Comment: @Pavitra what are you trying to accomplish?  do you just want them to be the same distance apart after the rotation?

Comment: @horsejockey : Yes I want them to be same distance apart